# Haskell product of list

Tags: list, parsing, haskell, product

So I need to write a program returning the product of a list of integers.Here is what I tried to make.But every time I get "parse error"on the = sign of the 4th line.

```
--product.hs
   product :: [Integer] -> Integer
   product []     = 1
   product i f = foldl (*) 1 [i..f]


    main = do
           print "Please enter first number"
           i <- readLn
           print "Please enter second number"
           f <- readLn
       print "The result is:"
       print (product i f)
```

I also tried with

```
    product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

but it still gives me parse error on the = sign

Comment: What is "the product of a list of integers"? I suppose you mean, the product of the integers in a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following code

```
product :: [Integer] -> Integer
product []     = 1
product i f = foldl (*) 1 [i..f]
```

you declare the type of `product` is `[Integer] -> Integer`, but in the second clause, you give it two parameters, this obviously does not match with its type.

You can define it simply like this

```
product xs = foldl (*) 1 xs
```

and use it like this

```
product [i..f]
```

---

By the way, `product` is a standard function offered by `Prelude`, with a similar (better) type and the same function.

Comment: With _a better_ type: `product :: Num a => [a] -> a`.

Answer (score -2):

Your parse error is probably due to inconsistent indentation. A good advice is to only use spaces for indentation.  While it is possible to use tabs, it is easy to trip up with an editor that doesn't treat tabs precisely the way Haskell does.

Here, all your function declarations need to be aligned vertically, as do all the statements in your do block.

Comment: Funny how being the only one to explain the reason for the actual problem *asked* for gets you downvoted. (Yes I know the other answer explained something that would have shown up later, but it didn't explain their *parsing* error.)